# how to convert a numeric into a char number?

Tags: string, char, numeric, atoi, atof

The problem is the next, generate a new string,
1. In the firt place : the firts letter of the name
2. In the second place : the third letter of the name
3. In the thitd place : The last letter of the name
4. In the fourth place :  the lenght of the character
int main(){

```
char cad1[10]={};
char cad2[4]={};
int  n ; 

cout<<"Ingresa un nombre de 4 o mas letras : " ;
cin.getline(cad1,10,'\n') ;

n =  strlen(cad1) ;
    
cad2[0] = cad1[0] ;
cad2[1] = cad1[2] ;
cad2[2] = cad1[n-1] ;
cad2[3] ??

cout<<cad2;
cout<<endl ;
system("PAUSE") ; return 0 ;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! If I understood your question correctly, you need to save the typed name length on the last char. If that's the case, just do:

```
cad2[3] = n + '0';
```

Comment: Yes you did, thanks can you explain why ?

Comment: Chars in the C programming language are represented by ASCII values, each value corresponding to a certain char. The ASCII value for an integer of value X  is 'X' (i.e. the char '9' is represented by the ASCII value 9). If you add an int and a char, you end up converting the int into a char, but since you're adding 0 to its current ASCII value, you end up with a char that corresponds to the int. Note: THIS ONLY WORKS FOR SINGLE DIGIT INTS!

Comment: another time thanks so much, i have another cuestion how it works for alot of digits ?